# Using String to get JSON Property

Tags: javascript, json

I want to use a string as a JSON property in JavaScript.

```
var knights = {
         'phrases': 'Ni!'
};

var x = 'phrases';

console.log(knights.x);         // Doesn't log "Ni!"
```

When I run this code, it obviously doesn't work because it interprets "x" and not the contents of the variable "x".

The full code in context on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/bMQJ9EDf

Is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: **This has nothing to do with JSON**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`knights.x` looks for a property named `x`. You want `knights[x]`, which is equivalent to `knights['phrases']` == `knights.phrases`.

Full code (fixing a couple of typos in your example):

```
var knights = {
         "phrases": "Ni!"
};

var x = 'phrases';

console.log(knights[x]); // logs Ni!
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this to access using variables having string values

```
kinghts[x]
```

Basically this is trick

```
kinghts[x]==knighted["phrases"]==knighted.phrases.
```

`knights.x` will get a key named `x`, So it'll return `undefined` here.

Answer (score 2):

`knights.x` is the same as `knights['x']` - retrieving a property under the key `x`. It's not accessing the variable `x` and substituting in the value. Instead, you want `knights[x]` which is the equivalent of `knights['phrases']`